# flutter an error occurred while executing doInBackground

Tags: android, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore with flutter and accidentally I try set and my app has crashed, I check the error I found that

```
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred
> while executing doInBackground() E/AndroidRuntime(14541):     at
> android.os.AsyncTask$4.done(AsyncTask.java:399)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:289)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541): Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: INTERNAL
> ASSERTION FAILED: A transaction object cannot be used after its update
> callback has been invoked.

> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.fail(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:46)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> com.google.firebase.firestore.util.Assert.hardAssert(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:31)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.ensureCommitNotCalled(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:246)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.write(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:241)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> com.google.firebase.firestore.core.Transaction.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:105)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:91)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> com.google.firebase.firestore.Transaction.set(com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore@@21.3.0:67)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$7.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:688)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> io.flutter.plugins.firebase.cloudfirestore.CloudFirestorePlugin$7.doInBackground(CloudFirestorePlugin.java:682)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> android.os.AsyncTask$3.call(AsyncTask.java:378)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  at
> java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> E/AndroidRuntime(14541):  ... 4 more
```

I found When I tried executing `transAction.set` the internet service not working , the service is on but connection field , while that the error occurred,

my code is

```
   await FireStoreHelper.firestore.runTransaction(
        (transAction) async {

      await transAction.set(
           ItemsHelper(item.id).ItemsRef.document(),
           {
              'title':'title',
              'price': 11.20
           }
   )
```